# Accumulating doubles vs ints

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point, double, cpu

The following code is slower when `a` is declared as a double, as opposed to an int:

```
double a = 0;
int j[1000];

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    a += (i * j[i]);
}
```

does this decrease in performance of double-precision addition arise from the compiler selecting different assembly instructions than what would be chosen if `a` had been declared as int?

I am trying to understand whether the CPU does any "conversions" of its own for single/double precision at run-time, which one cannot see in the assembly and cost execution time?

Comment: The instructions are different, and there's more work involved at a registry level. Your second question would have made more sense if there wasn't a execution time difference.

Comment: At the lowest level, floating point addition is more complicated than integer addition and will require different instructions.

Comment: I assume that you meant `i * j[i]`, because your code will not compile currently.

Comment: Wouldn't the (i * j) result have to be implicitly cast to double each iteration?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the first problem (`i*j`). Your code still invokes undefined behavior since the array `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: @DavidHammen I was relying on some common sense to show that j would require some values.... I dont have a surrounding function either- so it will never compile.

Comment: If it won't compile, why are you asking the question? There's a basic concept at this site, a "minimal working example". That MWE must compile, and in addition to being compilable, it should not invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us break down the expression in your loop into their parts. To do so, we will rewrite the code so that every line is exactly one assignment and one operation. When starting with the `int` version, it looks like the following:

```
// not depending on a
/* 1 */ auto t1 = j[i];
/* 2 */ auto t2 = i * j

// depending on decltype(a)
/* 3 */ decltype(a+t2) t3 = static_cast<decltype(a+t2)>(t2);
/* 4 */ decltype(a+t3) t4 = static_cast<decltype(a+t3)>(a);
/* 5 */ a = t3 + t4;
```

The first two operations do not depend on the type of `a` at all, and will do the exact same thing in either case.

However, starting with operation 3, there is a difference. The reason for that is for the addition of `a` and `t2` the compiler must first convert them to a common type. In the case where `a` is an integer, operations 3 and 4 do nothing at all (`int` + `int` yields `int`, so both casts convert `int`s to `int`s). In the case where `a` is a `double` however, `t2` must be converted to a `double` (`int` + `double` gives `double`) before the addition.

This means that the type of the addition in operation 5 is also different: It can be an `int` or a `double` addition. Ignoring the obvious aspect that a `double` will usually be twice as large as an `int`, this means that the computer needs to do something different at this point.

#### Implications for x64

When compiling this program for a modern x64 machine using an optimizing compiler, it should be noted that the whole program may be optimized away when stated as is. Assuming this does not happen and your compiler does not apply any illegal optimizations, and that you can live with the UB introduced by using uninitialized variables (the elements of `j`), the following could happen:

```
// not depending on a
MOV EAX, i // copy i to EAX register
IMUL j[i] // EAX = EAX * j[i] (high 32 bits are stored in EDX and ignored)

// if a is int
ADD a, EAX // integer addition: a += EAX

// else if a is double
CVTSI2SD XMM0, EAX // convert the multiplication result to double
ADDPD a, XMM0 // double addition: a += XMM0

// endif
```

A good compiler would unroll the loop a bit and interleave a few of these, since the loop limit is known. As you can see, there is at least a twofold increase in operations, and the instructions for a dependency chain. Also, the instructions in the second version are [slower](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) than the single one in the first version.

While I am sure that the second version could be stated in a far more efficient version, it should be noted that the integer `ADD` of the first version is one of the fastest operations on just about any CPU and will usually be faster than its floating point equivalent.

So, to answer your question: The CPU does indeed perform conversions between floating point and integers - which are visible in the assembly and have a (potentially significant) runtime cost.

#### What about single precision?

Since you asked about single precision as well, let us check what happens when using `float` instead:

```
// not depending on a
MOV EAX, i // copy i to EAX register
IMUL j[i] // EAX = EAX * j[i] (high 32 bits are stored in EDX and ignored)

// if a is float
CVTSI2SS XMM0, EAX // convert the multiplication result to float
ADDPS a, XMM0 // float addition: a += XMM0
```

The assembly does not show a significant difference (we just exchanged two `D` for `double` with `S` for `single`). And, interestingly enough, the difference in performance will be slight as well (e.g. a Haswell core will take 1 µop more for the conversion to double versus the conversion to float, while the addition itself shows identical performance).

#### Verification

To verify my claims, I have run your loop 2000000 times and ensured that `a` was not optimized away. The results are:

```
int   : 601.1 ms
float : 2567 ms
double: 2593 ms
```

Comment: Very nice and detailed explanation. One thing I'm wondering if it is a typo, you say: "a Haswell core will take 1 µop more for the conversion and the same performance for the addition" referring to the single precision operation in contrast to double precision. However your perf numbers show the single precision to be slightly faster. I'm curious if the float instruction is actually faster (not slower as stated). Maybe faster times are due to compiler optimization and superscalar magic? Or perhaps the times are simply within the margin of error?

Comment: @Apriori The `int` to `double` conversion is listed as 2 µops, while `int` to `float` only takes 1 - and the `int` to `int` "conversion" takes none at all (since it is not loaded into an XMM register at all)

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring that your example doesn't compile and that the array `j` is not initialized (I'm hoping you'll fix this).

Floating point arithmetic is in general slower than is integer arithmetic. However, your code has an even more expensive operation: Converting an integer to a floating point number. Your code suffers a double whammy (pun intended) by using mixed mode arithmetic.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic hasn't been appreciably slower on Intel processors since the original Pentium came out.

Comment: @tmyklebu - Floating point operations are still slower by a factor of two or so compared to integer operations. That's a drastic improvement over previous computers, where floating point computations were typically a factor of ten more expensive than integer computations. There's one exception to this improvement on floating point operations: Converting an integer to a double or a float remains an extremely expensive operation.